# Grammatik von "denn" zwischen zwei Kommas

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunction

> ..., und dann erst das Weitere überlegen, denn, das merkte er wohl,...
>
> -Die Verwandlung, Kafka

Kann  jemand das Benutzung von "denn" hier erklären? Ich habe es interessant gefunden, weil es zwischen Kommas gelegt sind.

Comment: Wenn man eine Frage zum Satzbau hat, ist es sehr sinnvoll, den ganzen Satz zu zitieren.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der vollständige Satz lautet

> Zunächst wollte er ruhig und ungestört aufstehen, sich anziehen und vor allem frühstücken, und dann erst das Weitere überlegen, **denn,** das merkte er wohl, **im Bett würde er mit dem Nachdenken zu keinem vernünftigen Ende kommen.**

Ich habe den zweiten, mit *denn* eingeleiteten kausalen Hauptsatz markiert. Dieses Stück *das merkte er wohl* ist ein weiterer eingeschobener Hauptsatz.

Diese Konstruktion mit dem eingeschobenen Hauptsatz ist im Deutschen nicht ungewöhnlich.

> Ich habe mir, jetzt weißt du es ja, deinen Schirm ausgeliehen.

Der eingeschobene Hauptsatz gibt dabei einen Umstand an, der für das Verständnis des äußeren Hauptsatzes wichtig ist. Deswegen fügt man ihn auch am besten dort ein, wo ansonsten ein passendes Adverbial stehen würde.