# Keine Kommas in eingeschobenem Satz?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Er erinnerte sich, schon öfters im Bett irgendeinen [!] **vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten**, leichten Schmerz empfunden zu haben, der sich dann beim Aufstehen als reine Einbildung herausstellte, und er war gespannt, wie sich seine heutigen Vorstellungen allmählich auflösen würden.
>
> Franz Kafka, die Verwandlung

Ich denke, an der Stelle in Klammern sollte ein Komma stehen, weil die folgende Idee wie ein eingefügter Haupsatz ist [(Schau hier)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73814/grammatik-von-denn-zwischen-zwei-kommas). Hab ich recht? Falls nicht, was habe ich verpasst?

Comment: Unabhängig davon, was nach dem Regelwerk korrekt wäre: Wenn ein eingeschobener Satz so komplex wird, dass er Kommata enthält, würde ich eine andere Lösung suchen. Sonst kommt es einfach zu schnell zu Missverständnissen, welches Komma welche Funktion hat, und wo der eingeschobene Satz anfängt und aufhört.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Mutig, Herrn Kafka vorzuschlagen, dass er seine Bücher hätte anders schreiben sollen...

Comment: @tofro Ich fürchte, bei mir muss man mit sowas rechnen ;) Aber im Ernst, meine Anmerkung richtet sich natürlich an Deutschlernende und andere Interessierte.

Answer (score 5):

Nein, es ist kein eingeschobener Hauptsatz. Das kannst du ganz leicht daran erkennen, dass es kein V2-Verb gibt.

Es handelt sich bei *vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten* um eine große Partizipialgruppe. Dafür ist Kafka berüchtigt, aber sie kommen auch in der Alltagssprache oft vor.

Solchen Gruppen vorangestellt ist ein Artikel, Prononomen, Zahlwort, der zum abschließenden Substantiv gehört. Sie enden in einem deklinierten Partizip I, II, oder Gerundiv. Sie zählen im Satz wie ein Adjektiv. Ich formuliere Kafka mal um:

> Er erinnerte sich, schon öfters im Bett **irgendeinen seltsamen, leichten Schmerz** empfunden zu haben, der sich dann beim Aufstehen als reine Einbildung herausstellte, und er war gespannt, wie sich seine heutigen Vorstellungen allmählich auflösen würden.

An dieser Umformulierung sieht man leichter, welchen Zweck Kafkas Komma vor *leichten* erfüllt: Es handelt sich um eine Aufzählung von Eigenschaften, die beide mit *irgendeinen* eingeleitet werden: *irgendeinen seltsamen* und *irgendeinen leichten*.

Das ist bei Adjektiven zwar nicht notwendig, bei einer Gruppe ist es aber vorteilhaft. Du **könntest** auch noch ein Komma nach *irgendeinen* setzen, dann ist es aber eine andere Aufzählung, in der *irgendeinen* gleichwertig neben *seltsamen* und *leichten* steht.

Comment: Also das ganze fettgedrueckter Satz funktioniert wie ein Adjektiv?

Comment: "… irgendeinen, den vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten, leichten Schmerz" Worauf bezieht sich "den"? und ich moechte auch fragen kannst du die unterscheid zwischen die Bedautung diese Satz und Orginal im Englisch erklaeren. Tut mir leid, aber ich koennte dein Erklaerung auf Deutsch darueber nicht gut folgen 

Comment: *Irgendeinen* gehört zu *Schmerz* und ist nicht Teil der Partizipialgruppe. Da letztere als Kopf ein adjektivisches Partizip und kein Nomen hat, kann diese nicht selbst durch einen Artikel eingeleitet werden.

Comment: @David Vogt: Stimmt. Es gehört zum Substantiv. Hmm.

Comment: @Hopeful Whitepiller: Ja, es funktioniert wie ein Adjektiv. Partizipien lassen sich grundsätzlich wie Adjektive verwenden, aber sie können eben auch Teil einer solchen Gruppe sein. Und vergiss mein Beispiel mit *den*, ich hatte nicht richtig darüber nachgedacht.

Answer (score 3):

Die Nominalphrase ist:

> irgendeinen Schmerz

Das Nomen *Schmerz* wird durch zwei adjektivische Attribute modifiziert:

> irgendeinen erzeugten, leichten Schmerz

Das Partizip *erzeugt* kann quasi wie ein Satz erweitert werden. Vergleiche, mit dem kursiven Teil in beiden Beispielen identisch:

> irgendeinen leichten Schmerz, der *vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugt* wurde
>
> irgendeinen *vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugt*en, leichten Schmerz

Was das Komma betrifft, gilt die Konvention, ein Komma zwischen Attributen zu setzen, wenn diese sich unabhängig voneinander auf das Nomen beziehen (Amtliche Regeln, [§ 71 E1](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201)).

> neue interessante Methoden
> neue, interessante Methoden

Im ersten Beispiel, ohne Komma, bezieht sich *neue* auf *interessante Methoden*; das suggeriert, dass es auch alte interessante Methoden gibt. Im zweiten Beispiel beziehen sich sowohl *neue* als auch *interessante* unabhängig voneinander auf *Methoden*; so entsteht kein Gegensatz zwischen neuen und alten interessanten Methoden.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist mit Sicherheit kein eingeschobener Hauptsatz - er hat nämlich kein Verb.

Was du gefunden hast, ist eine *eingeschobene Partizipialgruppe*, die hier auch einfach durch ein Adjektiv ersetzt werden könnte:

> ... er erinnerte sich, einen dumpfen, leichten Schmerz empfunden zu haben...

Bei solchen Partizipialgruppen *können* (solange das konjugierte Verb des Satzes vor dem Einschub kommt) Kommas gesetzt werden, um den Satz leichter lesbar zu machen, *müssen* aber nicht. Nach heutigen Regeln würde man aber entweder den gesamten Einschub durch Kommas begrenzen oder sie ganz weglassen - Was Kafka hier getan hat (vorne keins, hinten eins) scheint mir eher ungewöhnlich, man könnte das möglicherweise durch das weitere Attribut ("leichten") als Aufzählung betrachten - dann hat das hintere Komma nicht direkt etwas mit der Partizipialgruppe zu tun, sondern ist durch die Aufzählung begründet.

Comment: Das hintere Komma hat er gesetzt, weil es sich außerdem um eine Aufzählung handelt.

Comment: @janka Sachichdoch?

Answer (score 2):

Die Partizialgruppe ist nicht ein Einschub. Stattdessen handelt es sich um eine attributive Partizipialgruppe, und zwar in einer Aufzählung. Das Komma steht nur zwischen den aufgezählten Gliedern, nicht davor.

### Die Partizialgruppe ist kein Einschub

Der Originalsatz lautet wie folgt:

1. Er erinnerte sich, schon öfters im Bett irgendeinen vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten, leichten Schmerz empfunden zu haben […].

Zur vereinfachten Analyse isoliere ich den Nebensatz:

2. Er hat schon öfters im Bett irgendeinen vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten, leichten Schmerz empfunden.

Wenn die Partizipialgruppe «vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten» ein Einschub wäre, dann müsste sie sich ins Vorfeld verschieben lassen. Dies ist aber nicht der Fall:

3. *Ungrammatisch:* * Vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten, hat er schon öfters im Bett irgendeinen leichten Schmerz empfunden.

Eingeschobene Partizipialgruppen sind eigenständige Satzglieder und lassen sich ins Vorfeld verschieben. Ein Beispiel wäre der folgende Satz:

4. Er hat schon öfters im Bett, vielleicht ungeschickt liegend, irgendeinen leichten Schmerz empfunden.
5. *Im Vorfeld:* Vielleicht ungeschickt liegend, hat er schon öfters im Bett irgendeinen leichten Schmerz empfunden.

### Die Partizipialgruppe ist attributiv

Die Partizipialgruppe «vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten» ist attributiv. Das Partizip «erzeugten» ist ein Attribut von «Schmerz» (genau so wie das Adjektiv «leichten»). Die Erweiterung «vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen» ist eine Adverbiale von «erzeugten», die sich mit *wie?* erfragen lässt:

6. Irgendeinen *wie* erzeugten, leichten Schmerz? – Irgendeinen *vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen* erzeugten, leichten Schmerz.

Die attributive Partizipialgruppe als Ganzes lässt sich wie jedes Attribut mit *was für ein:e?* erfragen:

7. Was für einen leichten Schmerz? – Einen vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugten.

Attributive Partizipialgruppen lassen sich wie jedes Attribut in Relativsätze mit «sein» umformen (die ebenfalls Attribute sind):

7. Irgendeinen leichten Schmerz, der vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugt worden ist.

Eine andere Umformungsmöglichkeit für Attribute ist ein Prädikativum mit «sein»:

8. Irgendein Schmerz ist vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugt (und leicht).

Dies erleichtert die Erfragbarkeit:

9. Wie ist irgendein (leichter) Schmerz? – Vielleicht durch ungeschicktes Liegen erzeugt.

In der Ersatzprobe lässt sich die attributive Partizialgruppe durch ein gewöhnliches Adjektiv ersetzen:

10. Er hat schon öfters im Bett irgendeinen blauen, leichten Schmerz empfunden.

### Komma

Aufzählungen von mehreren Attributen werden nach den gewöhnlichen Regeln durch Komma getrennt (oder nicht, vgl. Amtliches Regelwerk [§ 71 E1](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par71E1)). Vornedran haben sie aber kein Komma, weder nach heutigen noch nach früheren Regeln.

Comment: Man kann auch hier von *Partizip(ial)gruppe* bzw. *-phrase* sprechen (wie z.B. die Duden-Grammatik), als Bezeichnung nach der Form. *Attribut* bezeichnet die Funktion; es gibt attributive und nicht attributive bzw. satzwertige Partizipphrasen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Merci für den Hinweis, das stimmt – ich habe die Terminologie also verbessert.